# Labcoat, lab-coat or lab coat?

Tags: word-usage

As in the title,

Labcoat, lab-coat or lab coat?

Which is the correct version? And is there a convention I can use for other similar combinations of words.

Comment: Look the word up in a couple good dictionaries and choose a version. And no there is no convention... although compound words tend, over time, to go from a space to a hyphen to no joiner, so in the opposite order of your listing for lab coat. Today used to be spelt to-day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[When is it necessary to use a hyphen in writing a compound word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word)* Also see *[What's the most preferred spelling of auto fill, auto-fill, and autofill?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146660)* and *[“Stand up comedy”, “standup comedy”, or “stand-up comedy”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66029)* — ultimately, it is a question of style, so consult your editor or style manual.